# Node js Mysql query execute

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node.js to connect to Mysql database. I succeded in making the connection. However, several attempts to insert data have failed.

Can somoeone please look at the code of the js file executed in node ?

This is the js file to execute by node.js:

```
let mysql = require("mysql")

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'daniel',
    password : '',
    database : 'company',
});

connection.connect()

connection.query('INSERT INTO Employees (emp_no,emp_name,salary,reports_to)  VALUES  (1, "Manos", 1500, "Director")');
```

And this is the error I get:

```
node mysqlconnection3.js
/root/nodejs/mysqlconnection3.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { \// Read the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql.
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: See if it is thowing the error on connect 
`connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });`

Comment: From the [Docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries): _The simplest form of .query() is .query(sqlString, callback), where a SQL string is the first argument and the second is a callback_. Your example only includes the SQL String. Your best bet is to start with the Docs, use the examples provided as templates, replace only what you need to, and don't remove stuff unless you're certain it won't break things - or you have the necessary code in place to catch errors.